# how to disable an animation just for chrome

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, marquee

well this is my problem..

```
<html>
  <body>
    <marquee id="introtext" scrollamount="150" behavior="slide" direction="left">
      <p>
         this is the sliding text.
      </p>
    </marquee>
  </body>
</html>
```

What chrome does is just weard.
it repeats the "marquee" action after 4 seconds.

what can i do to prevent this? or just fully disable this marquee but still keep this id ,
because this is used for other css effects?

sincerely,

santino

Comment: The `<marquee>` tag has been obsolete for a while. It was originally a vendor-specific (IE) tag.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try loop="0" :

```
<marquee id="introtext" scrollamount="150" behavior="slide" direction="left" loop="0">
```

Answer (score 0):

> what can i do to prevent this? or just fully disable this marquee but
>   still keep this id , because this is used for other css effects?

From `<marquee id="introtext" scrollamount="150" behavior="slide" direction="left">`

To `<div id="introtext">`

If you want just to remain with ID of block. But that deletes marquee.